# PHP Exec, not executing variables

Tags: php, exec

I'm still very new to PHP so sorry if this seems simple to some people.

So I have a PHP Script that I would like to run, however when I run the script the variable in the script doesn't get executed. I'm using php's exec function.

```
<?php

$url = $_POST['url'];

echo exec('youtube-dl \--extract-audio \--audio-format \mp3 \$url 2>&1', $output);
print_r($output);

?>
```

Everything seems to work, however the `$url` variable never gets inserted and the script returns with the error `"We could not find a video by the URL of $url"`

Now if I type `"echo $url;"` it echos the url like normal.

Any ideas as to why this wouldn't work in the exec command? All help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: `"youtube-dl \--extract-audio \--audio-format \mp3 \$url 2>&1"` try that. Variables don't get parsed in single quotes.

Comment: also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thanks to Fred -ii- in the comments. I found out variables don't get parsed in single quotes ( ' ' ).

Instead I had to use double quotes ( " " ).

Thank you guys again so much for the help!

Comment: Great and you're welcome, however answers usually come from the person who provided the answer ;-) where you get to accept it after.